# undefined method `namespace'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, sinatra

I'm trying implement a namespace(with **sinatra-contrib gem**) routing for Sinatra app and have an error after I'm trying to start the server:

```
undefined method `namespace' for GuessApp:Class
```

*app.rb*

```
require 'sinatra'
require 'sinatra/namespace'
require 'haml'
require_relative 'routes/init'
require_relative 'models/init'
require_relative 'helpers/init'

class GuessApp < Sinatra::Base
  register Sinatra::Namespace
end
```

*routes/init.rb*

```
require_relative "books"
require_relative "stars"
```

*routes/books.rb*

```
class GuessApp < Sinatra::Base
  namespace '/books' do
    @title = "Books"

    get '' do
      @books = Book.all
      haml :books, layout: :layout
    end
  end
end
```

Without namespace this route works fine.

Comment: How are you launching the app? It looks like you are loading `books.rb` before `app.rb`, so the `namespace` extension isn’t available.

Comment: `thin -R config.ru -a 127.0.0.1 -p 8080 start`.  
In _config.ru_  
`require File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), 'app.rb')`
`run GuessApp.new`

Comment: Where's the code the includes books.rb?

Comment: in _app.rb_ after `require "sinatra/namespace"`. I have updated information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You `require 'sinatra/namespace'` before you require `books.rb`, but you only `register Sinatra::Namespace` in the `GuessApp` app *after* you require it. Requiring alone only makes it available in classic style apps.

You need to make sure `Sinatra::Namespace` is registered in `GuessApp` before you try to use `namespace`, something like this in `app.rb`:

```
require 'sinatra'
require 'sinatra/namespace'
require 'haml'    

class GuessApp < Sinatra::Base
  register Sinatra::Namespace
end    

require_relative 'routes/init'
require_relative 'models/init'
require_relative 'helpers/init'
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work for me. I tried requiring `'sinatra/namespace'` and use this register statement in my ApplicationController but the app always complains that it doesn't know anything about `Sinatra::Namespace` I load my app through `config.ru`. Any chance you can give me a hint? Thanks